# VNC into workstations, send messages etc?

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, vnc, messaging

I am using Windows Server 2008 with Windows XP workstations. Occasionally I flick though the workstations at random and see what people are doing. Sometimes, albeit rarely, I see them doing something that's against the terms of use for the network (as defined by management).

Ideally, I would like to be able to send the user a message that pops up explaining that they shouldn't be doing that and I would be grateful if they stopped.

Additionally I would like to be able to disable their keyboard and mouse when supporting the users via VNC to prevent them from hijacking what I'm doing.

I use a Mac mostly when supporting users so if there is any software that would work on a Mac it would be great. If not, can any Windows applications do this?

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat tangential, but perhaps there are better ways to detect behavior that violates policy (analysis of Snort/Web proxy logs, etc), or at least ways that reduce the amount of manual supervision you perform?

Answer (score 1):

Log me in is a great application for this
you can lock they're keyboard, blank the screen and take control and send a message as necessary. 
It also works with a Mac
The free version does all of this, the pro version has even more functionality
www.logmein.com
Chris

Comment: All of the workstations already have a VNC server installed, can I use logmein with the existing VNC applications?

Comment: You can't use it with VNC, but logmein is a much better program. It is web accessible from anywhere, with authentication and has much more functionality then VNC. I would try it out to see the difference.

Comment: I like the look of it, but it's a shame it can't use the existing VNC servers. I'll take a look though. Thanks!

Comment: I have used VNC in the past but switched over to this now. It doesn't require me to change any firewall rules on the gateway or the clients and I get a single web interface for managing all my machines.

Comment: Do you have the Enteprise $200 a year version?

Comment: The Enterprise version is worth it if you have multiple people using the account and you want to control access, but if its just you it's not necessary. They will give you a trial of the enterprise version if you want to try it out, but try the free one first would be my advise.

Comment: I use the free version

Comment: Well, we have 33 computers that only I need to access them. I am confused as to how to set it up for free. I'm presuming it's not the Logmein Central version?

Comment: Logmein Central is used to manage the machines, but just create a free account for yourself, go to each computer and log in with your account and select "add computer" manually for eacho computer.

Comment: You don't need "logmein central" or Logmein Enterprise" unless you want the additional features. Everything you were looking for can be done in the free version.

Comment: Give me a vote if you like the answer :D

Comment: oh and I've used Team Viewer before as well.... I find this one better.

Comment: On a side Note, to the comment below, you  may want to try using some software like Untangle to block this behaviour in the first place
http://www.untangle.com/

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Also Team Viewer could be a good solutions...

http://www.teamviewer.com/download/tv6.aspx